# jquery sticky Panel-v1.4.1 - iphone, ipad fix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, jquery-plugins, fixed

First of all i would like to give you some appreciation for the sticky panel 1.4.1 plugin it works accurant and fast i'm veary happy whit it!

The only problem is the plugin does not support iphone - ipad at the moment.

would this be a option for the future or is it not posible at all?

Or am i doing something wrong here?

here the snippet of the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function () {
        var stickyPanelOptions = {
            topPadding: 0,
            afterDetachCSSClass: "BoxGlow_Grey2",
            savePanelSpace: true
        };
        $("#mainContentNav").stickyPanel(stickyPanelOptions);
     });
</script>

<div id="mainContentNav">
    <ul id="fixedNav">
        <li><a href="#" class="Button baselink"><div id="1">1</div></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="Button baselink"><div id="2">2</div></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="Button baselink"><div id="3">3</div></a></li>
     </ul>
</div>

#mainContentNav {
    z-index: 2;
    background: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    height: 60px;
    width: 500px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #000;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none; 
}
```

Hope someone could help me maybe.

Comment: already fixed the refresh problem only the iphone / ipad problem left!

Answer (score 0):

I'v added iPad support, fixed the refresh bug and added onDetached & onReattached events.